# Incorrect date on the x-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Please tell me what the problem is, constantly displays 01.01.xxxx, although in the tooltip correct date.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awhr7y74/)

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
        formatter: function () {
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %m %Y', this.value);
        }
      },
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'reg',
        data: [[1392760800000, 60], [1420149600000, 3]] // 1392760800000 - 18.02.2014, 1420149600000 - 02.01.2015

    }, {
        name: 'app',
        data: [[1392760800000, 0], [1420149600000, 0]]

    }, {
        name: 'dec',
        data: [[1392760800000, 0], [1420149600000, 0]]

    }, {
        name: 'deac',
        data: [[1392760800000, 60], [1420149600000, 3]]

    }]
});
```

Comment: The dates below are correct, if you think of all four columns as having the date at the very middle of them (between green and orange). How would you like it to appear?

Comment: date in the tooltip and on the x-axis are different, correct tooltip

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit unclear. When you say incorrect date on xAxis do you mean incorrect number or is it incorrect format? Because if the number it's wrong, this is what you pass to `formatter` in `xAxis`. If you convert `this.value` to Date(), you will get exactly what's displayed on the screen.

Comment: They are not incorrect, they are just not what you think they are. The x-axis is a timeline, and not aligned to your points. See [this paint image](http://i.imgur.com/ywhgOd4.png). So the question is, how do you want it to look?

Comment: Ok thanks, please tell me how can I display the date of my points?

Comment: You can use [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions) / [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner)

Answer (score 0):

Axis labels are displayed not for columns but for beginning of years because of size of chart and scale of x axis.
You could fix that i.e. by setting positions for x axis ticks.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/awhr7y74/2/

For this you can use `tickPositions` (used in example) or alternatively - tickPositioner.
See API for more information - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner